# Execute IntegrationTests in an already running Hybris server

Tags: spring, integration-testing, sap-commerce-cloud

My Hybris IntegrationTest classes extend the **de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.ServicelayerTransactionalTest.java**. When I run such a class in Eclipse using **"Run As -> JUnit Test"** option, a Hybris server spawns, executes that class & then shuts down. This is the behavior for every IntegrationTest class I run which is time-consuming. I was wondering is there any approach to execute these classes in an already running Hybris server so I don't have to worry about server startup time on every run ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes there is the JUnit testweb frontent with the URL `/test` that lists all unit/integration tests and offers a search / selection so you can execute exactly which test classes (and methods) you want.

You can even initialize the junit tenant from that UI.

The out of the box URL for this is: `https://localhost:9002/test/`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks,this helps a lot.However the url doesn't list any test suite of 3rd party libraries like cucumber. It seems only classes tagged with test annotations of hybris sdk (@IntegrationTest, @UnitTest) are scanned & listed. Is there any alternative to list Cucumber annotations tagged classes as well ?

Comment: sorry, that I don't know :)

Comment: acceleratoraddon/web/testsrc how to run these tests.. the web module for custom extension is disabled in the tenant page of hac